# iPhone SDK paypal integration API

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk

I have to integrate Paypal API into my iPhone App. I have included required libraries also. But I am getting only one following error.

> "_SecTrustEvaluate", referenced from:
> -[PPMobileConnect
> connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:]
> in libPayPalMEP.a(PPMobileConnect.o)
> -[AdaptivePaymentsSOAP11BindingOperation
> connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:]
> in libPayPalMEP.a(AdaptivePayments.o)
> ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld
> returned 1 exit status

How could I resolve this?

I include `libxml2,libz` also.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

Add the Security.framework. Hope it help!